# Map appsettings.json to class

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration

I'm trying to convert appsettings.json to C# class

I use `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` to read the configuration from appsettings.json

I write the following code using reflection but I'm looking for a better solution

```
foreach (var (key, value) in configuration.AsEnumerable())
{
    var property = Settings.GetType().GetProperty(key);
    if (property == null) continue;
    
    object obj = value;
    if (property.PropertyType.FullName == typeof(int).FullName)
        obj = int.Parse(value);
    if (property.PropertyType.FullName == typeof(long).FullName)
        obj = long.Parse(value);
    property.SetValue(Settings, obj);
}
```

Comment: Options pattern solves this elegantly. [Check out the offical docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Build configuration from *appsettings.json* file:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional = false)
            .Build()
```

Then add *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder* nuget package. And you will have extensions to bind configuration (or configuration section) to the existing or new object.

E.g. you have a settings class (btw by convention it's called options)

```
public class Settings
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And *appsettings.json*

```
{
  "Foo": "Bob",
  "Bar": 42
}
```

To bind configuration to new object you can use [`Get<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_Get__1_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_) extension method:

```
var settings = config.Get<Settings>();
```

To bind to existing object you can use [`Bind(obj)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_Bind_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_Object_):

```
var settings = new Settings();
config.Bind(settings);
```

Comment: there is no Get and Bind method

Comment: @AliRezaBeigy then missed the part of adding Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder package

Comment: @AliRezaBeigy bit late, i had this, i didn't add the .Build() at the end of instantiating the config var

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Dictionary` to get the json, and then use `JsonSerializer` to convert the json.

```
public IActionResult get()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> settings = configuration
        .GetSection("Settings")
        .Get<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(settings);

        var setting = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Settings>(json);

        return Ok();
    }
```

Here is the model

```
public class Settings
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public string property2 { get; set; }
}
```

In appsettings.json

```
 "Settings": {
  "property1": "ap1",
  "property2": "ap2"
 },
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm shocked nobody has suggested using the `IOptions` pattern or even asked if this a system involving DI (Dependency Injection). If the system is indeed using DI, I would suggest using the `IOptions` pattern described here [Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options) as it not only allows for the options to be injected where they're needed, but also allows for change notifications so you can receive configuration changes and act on them.